# Count number of iTunes songs by Artist with a name starting with a letter

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

I am brand new to Applescript. I would like a script that would list the artist and the number of songs in that artist's folder. I would like to do it just for artists whose names starts with A. When I am ready, I would then get the list for artist whose names starts with B, and so on. I did find this post: "What's the fastest way in iOS to retrieve the number of songs for a specific artist?" Maybe that script would work but I don't know how to modify this line "if (artistName != nil)" to get what I want. Also, I don't know where the information is stored so I can retreive it "// store the new count
[artists setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numSongs] forKey:artistName]; Oh, and I am not using iOS I will be using osx. Perhaps I could modify this script that I found. It gets the number of albums by artist.

```
MPMediaQuery *albumQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
NSArray *albumCollection = [albumQuery collections];
NSCountedSet *artistAlbumCounter = [NSCountedSet set];
[albumCollection enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MPMediaItemCollection  *album, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
NSString *artistName = [[album representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
[artistAlbumCounter addObject:artistName];
}];
NSLog(@"Artist Album Counted Set: %@", artistAlbumCounter);
```

I appreciate any help that you can offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to look at iOS code and ObjectiveC at that in order to figure out what you should do with Applescript! In any case, here is what you want.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    # Get playlist currently selected 
    set myPlayList to view of window 1

    set s to (every track in myPlayList whose artist begins with "g")
    repeat with t in s
        log name of t
    end repeat
    log (count of s)
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you Vic! I wasn't sure just what I was looking at as you so rightly pointed out. I definitely wanted an Applescript.

Comment: Use `set trackNames to (name of every track in myPlayList whose artist begins with "g")`. If you've a significant number of tracks, it will be much quicker as it gets all the information in a single command instead of having to send an additional Apple event for each track found.

Comment: foo, Would the code look like this?  `tell application "iTunes"
        # Get playlist currently selected 
        set myPlayList to view of window 1

        set tracknames to (name of every track in myPlayList whose artist begins with "g")

        log (count of tracknames)
    end tell`

Answer (score 1):

This one uses the `selected playlist` (or, if that fails for some reason, the whole library) and goes from `A` to `Z`. Replace the `log` parts with your code. To see how it works make sure in `Script-Editor` it shows the `Log` and for a better view select the `Messages` *tab*. Only `file tracks` are handled.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    try
        set selectedPlayList to view of window 1
    on error
        beep
        set selectedPlayList to (container of browser window 1) -- whole library (I think)
    end try
end tell

set totalItems to 0

repeat with i from (id of "A") to (id of "Z")

    set thisLetter to (character id i)

    log "-----------------------------------------------------------"

    tell application "iTunes"
        try

            set currentItems to (file tracks in selectedPlayList whose artist begins with thisLetter)
            set countItems to number of items in currentItems
            set totalItems to totalItems + countItems

            set s to "s"
            if countItems = 1 then set s to ""
            log (countItems as text) & " item" & s & " for artists starting with the letter " & quoted form of thisLetter
            log "-----------------------------------------------------------"

            repeat with i from 1 to countItems
                set thisItem to item i of currentItems

                tell thisItem -- this is like "tell file track x". Shortens the code because we can use "artist" instead of "artist of thisItem"

                    log (i as text) & ". " & quoted form of (get artist) & " | " & quoted form of (get name) & "    [ " & time & " ] "

                end tell

            end repeat


        on error the error_message number the error_number
            beep
            display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
            return
        end try

    end tell

end repeat


log "-----------------------------------------------------------"
log "Items: " & totalItems as text
```

Comment: This is awesome! I am afraid to do A to Z (all at once) because there are 55,000 songs and I don't know how long that would take. Maybe I can tweak it.

Comment: Yes, use only the parts you want. Add 'if i > 50 then exit repeat' after the 'tell thisItem' -block (after 'end tell') to only do 50 items per letter. But… it's not really a good way to overview all tracks because artist-names starting not with a letter get missed and names starting with "The", like "The Beatles", are all under "T".

Comment: Cool. I think it is bizarre that The Beatles (and other groups starting with 'The') are under 'T'. Apple should fix that. You won't see that in Library Catalogs, librarians figured that one out a long time ago.

Comment: 55K tracks is the sort of number where efficiency makes a difference. As noted above, using `set {trackName, artistName, trackTime} to {name, artist, time} of (every track...)` will get all of the required information using just 3 Apple events _in total_, instead of 3*N+1 events (where N=number of tracks found).